# My second System.out.print is not printing but is compiling fine

Tags: java, system.out

I am using this class as part of another program and I'm wondering why the second `System.out.print` doesn't print anything. I'm doing the same with other algorithms and it works just fine. It is still inside the method so I am unsure as to why it will not print

```
public class EnhancedBubbleSort
{
   int temp = 0;
   boolean sorted = false;
   long counter1 = 0, counter2 = 0;

   public void sort(int[] numbers)
   {  
      System.out.print("Before Enhanced Bubble Sort: ");
      for(int a: numbers)
         System.out.print(a + ", ");

      int lastSwap = numbers.length-1;
      for(int i=1; i<numbers.length; i++) 
      {
         boolean is_sorted = true;
         int currentSwap = -1;

         for(int j=0; j < lastSwap; j++) 
         {
            counter1++;
            if(numbers[j] > numbers[j+1]) 
            {
               counter2++;
               temp = numbers[j];
               numbers[j] = numbers[j+1];
               numbers[j+1] = temp;
               is_sorted = false;
               currentSwap = j;
            }
         }  
         if(is_sorted) 
            return;
         lastSwap = currentSwap;
      }

      System.out.print("\nAfter Enhanced Bubble Sort: ");
      for(int a: numbers)
         System.out.print(a + ", "); 
   }
}
```

Comment: `if(is_sorted) 
            return;` what do you think that does?

Comment: You have a `return` that should be a `break`.

Comment: i have since fixed it, using break instead of return in the if(sorted)

Answer (score 1):

Please modify the code as below and it works just fine:

```
class EnhancedBubbleSort
{
   int temp = 0;
   boolean sorted = false;
   long counter1 = 0, counter2 = 0;

   public void sort(int[] numbers)
   {  
      System.out.print("Before Enhanced Bubble Sort: ");
      for(int a: numbers)
      System.out.print(a + ", ");

      int lastSwap = numbers.length-1;
      for(int i=1; i<numbers.length; i++) 
      {
         boolean is_sorted = true;
         int currentSwap = -1;

         for(int j=0; j < lastSwap; j++) 
         {
            counter1++;
            if(numbers[j] > numbers[j+1]) 
            {
               counter2++;
               temp = numbers[j];
               numbers[j] = numbers[j+1];
               numbers[j+1] = temp;
               is_sorted = false;
               currentSwap = j;
            }
         }  
         if(is_sorted) 
          break;   // Use break statement instead of return one
      lastSwap = currentSwap;
      }
      System.out.print("\nAfter Enhanced Bubble Sort: ");
      for(int a: numbers)
         System.out.print(a + ", "); 
   }
}
```

Output:

```
jshell> new EnhancedBubbleSort().sort(data)
Before Enhanced Bubble Sort: 1, 2, 3, 4, 
After Enhanced Bubble Sort: 1, 2, 3, 4,
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `if(is_sorted) return;` you leave `void sort()` and no further statements will be executed. What you want to do instead is `if(is_sorted) break;`, leaving the `for` loop.